# How to add a new page in an XSL-FO file

Tags: xsl-fo

Right now I am working with XSLT to create a report in XSL-FO. I have different different templates in my XSLT files for different section in the report. While generating the report I am getting a particular section on half page and other half on the second page; so we have decided to move the whole section to a new page. Now I am really confused what tag I should add to the template in XSLT so that it can be on a new page. I am really new to XSLT and need help.

Comment: Feel free to edit the question if required...

Comment: My understanding is that you are transforming an XML file and instead of having its two sections processed into two new sections, your goal is to have only one resulting section?

Comment: XSLT knows nothing about pages. It just knows XML. Are you transforming it into XSL-FO or HTML? Maybe something else?

Comment: @Buffalo thnx for the reply sir... but I have only one section... Its just the page displaying problem... For some data it displays properly for some it don't. I heard there is something known as break. Do you have any idea???

Comment: @MarkusJarderot Yepp I am transforming it in XSLT-FO...

Comment: @mzjn thnx for the edit... It made the question perfect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can suport HTML reports, use the XLST to create an HTML docuent and then use CSS to manage your page breaks

```
<style type="text/css">
h1{
page-break-before: always;
}
</style>
```

Trying to "guess" where to put page breaks in HTML is a challenge due to font sizes, etc. Usually it's best to use a printer friendly format (e.g. PDF) if you want nicely printed material. However, HTML+CSS can give you a quick and dirty solution.

**Edit**

Your comment mentions XSL-FO. Perhaps the [break-before](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/prop_break-before.asp) property would help

Comment: Hi Brad,
Thanks a ton it worked...You just saved my Life... It was an very urgent client issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of small sections, you could put an `fo:block` around each and use `keep-together.within-page` (http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#keep-together) on the `fo:block` so that the sections stay together as much as possible.